# How to split a list in python by values lower and higher then x

Tags: python

```
 from random import randint

print("The safe has been locked for the night...")
combination = randint(1,1000)

safe_locked = True
int_invalid = True
duplicate = True
guesses_list = list()
one_o_one = 1001


while safe_locked == True:

  while int_invalid == True:
    try:
      guess = int(input("Take your guess at the combination... "))
      if guess in guesses_list :
        guess += one_o_one
        duplicate = False
      if guess in range(1,1001):
        guesses_list.append(guess)
        break
      else:
        if duplicate == False:
          print("Invalid combination! Make sure combination isn't a duplicate...")
        else:
          print("Invalid combination! Make sure combination is within (1-1000)...")
          int_invalid = True
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid combination! Make sure combination only includes numbers...")

  guesses_list.sort()


  if guess == combination:
    print("The safe has opened... The jewels are yours!")
    safe_locked = False
  else:
    if guess > combination:
      print("The combination is lower...")
    else:
      print("The combination is higher...")

  print(guesses_list)


  if safe_locked == False:
    break
```

Hi guys,

So I am new to python and making this basic game. I want to split the guesses list into two new lists. The first list being all the values below the combination value and the other list being above the combination value.

The reason for this is so I can take the highest value in the first list and lowest in second list to display the 'guessing range'.

Thanks

EDIT (hopefully this makes it easier to understand the issue):

Hi Calestini: in my game the player guesses the combination to the safe and is told if it’s higher or lower. To display the range of the possible combinations using previous guesses I wanted to have a list of the guesses already made and split the list into two. I want one list to contain all the guesses underneath the correct combination and another list containing all the guesses above the correct combination. This would let me take the highest value of the first list and the lowest list of the second list to create a range of possible correct combinations. The problem is I don’t know how to split the list into two halves in between the correct combination.

Comment: Hello George, thanks for giving us context and including the code, but we also need a specfic question. What exactly is the problem? Does the code not work? If not, what is the expected behaviour and what is the actual behaviour? Does it throw an excepton? At what line? Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Calestini: in my game the player guesses the combination to the safe and is told if it’s higher or lower. To display the range of the possible combinations using previous guesses I wanted to have a list of the guesses already made and split the list into two. I want one list to contain all the guesses underneath the correct combination and another list containing all the guesses above the correct combination.

Comment: This would let me take the highest value of the first list and the lowest list of the second list to create a range of possible correct combinations. The problem is I don’t know how to split the list into two halves in between the correct combination.

Comment: That task only needs a very small example code. Try creating a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
lower_then = [_ for _ in array if _<x]
greater_then = [_ for _ in array if _>x]
```

Comment: Code only answers are not appreciated in SO. Please add some explanation to it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
#input list
y=np.array([3,4,-1,5,6,7,3,3,6,8,6,10,9])
#your x- value to be guessed
x=7
#left and right limit
a,b=y[y<x],y[y>x]

print(a,b)
```

Output:

```py
[ 3  4 -1  5  6  3  3  6  6] [ 8 10  9]
```